# On clicking button the app goes back to homepage

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I am new and working on an app, so I have created homepage of it and then when we click on anyone of it it opens a new activity in which when clicking the button to get the answer doesnt work and it goes back to the homepage. Please help me solve this!
This is my code of main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CardView Currency = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Currency);
        CardView Area = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Area);
        CardView Length = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Length);
        CardView Temperature = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Temperature);
        CardView Time = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Time);
        CardView Weight = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.Weight);

        Currency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Currency.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Weight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Weight.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Time.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Length.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Length.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Area.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Area.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Temperature.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Temperature.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is of my new activity to open at homepage and convert the value

```
public class Weight extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(Weight.this, "Request Proceeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String s = editText.getText().toString();
                Integer.parseInt(s);
                int kg = Integer.parseInt(s);
                double pound = 2.205 * kg;
                textView.setText("The corresponding value in Pound is" + pound);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your app is crashing you need to post the logcat errors also

Comment: Assuming you mean MainActivity by "homepage," when you click the "button" (in Weight), instead of showing the text (pound value), does it "goes back to the homepage"? Based on your code, once you clicked the "Weight" button, you would move to the Weight activity; if you click the "button" then it should set the text. Since you didn't mention that you're getting an error, I'd assume your app doesn't crash; however, if you are, please post the logcat.

Comment: Also, you may want to use a holder (and perhaps onBindViewHolder).

Comment: @David Lee yes it does go to weight activity but then when I type the value there which I had set and click button to convert to pounds it goes back to main activity that is homepage where we can select the units to convert

Comment: Also I will try onBindViewHolder to see if it works

Comment: I'm not able to replicate such behavior. After clicking a CardView (Weight), it goes to the "Weight" activity; then, if I enter an integer and click the button, it shows me the correct value (without 'going back' to the MainActivity).

Comment: Well it doesnt show any errors after I click more than 2 times on it it shows app stopped working and are you on discord?? I could explain you more about the problem